# AWS Protect Websocket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, security, websocket

Problem is how to secure websocket connections and actions.

I have a websocket server on AWS and my Unity app uses this websocket and it works perfectly. But if someone take the wss uri, the websocket will be used. How can I prevent this situation?

I researched a lot of resources but I didn't find any useful information about this problem. Everyone say, use api key. But if I create an API key how can I protect this key on client side?

And I have a extra question: Is can possible anybody take the wss URI with sniffing the app network? Or request/response body?

Thanks.

Comment: The point is - you can't protect keys on the client side. Think about how you protect REST endpoints. You can use similar means on websocket level. Though, public REST endpoints can not really be protected. The same goes about web sockets.

Comment: To answer your very last question, `wss` is Web Socket Secure, which is an encrypted connection like `https`. So no, you can't sniff the request/response body, because that will be encrypted.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)